# High performance number formatting

Tags: r

For my json encoder, I would like to print a set of numbers with `n` decimals. Two ways are:

```
x <- c(1,2,pi)
n <- 2
format(x, digits = n, nsmall = n, trim = TRUE, drop0trailing = TRUE)
formatC(x, digits = n, format = "f", drop0trailing = TRUE)
```

However the `drop0trailing` parameter seems to introduce a big (~10x) performance regression:

```
x <- rnorm(1e6)
system.time(format(x, digits = n, nsmall = n, trim = TRUE))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.584   0.000   0.584
system.time(format(x, digits = n, nsmall = n, trim = TRUE, drop0trailing = TRUE))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.763   0.040   5.799
```

Is there an alternative way of printing numbers with `n` decimals that is faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command

```
as.character(round(x, n))
# [1] "1"    "2"    "3.14"
```

should be much faster. The `options(scipen = k)` controls if and when it jumps to scientific notation.

Another option is

```
sub("\\.0+$", "", sprintf(paste0("%.", n, "f"), x))
# [1] "1"    "2"    "3.14"
```

The advantage of this command is that the result is not in scientific notation.

Performance checks:

```
f1 <- function() format(x, digits = n, nsmall = n, trim = TRUE, drop0trailing = TRUE)
f2 <- function() formatC(x, digits = n, format = "f", drop0trailing = TRUE)
f3 <- function() as.character(round(x, n))
f4 <- function() sub("\\.0+$", "", sprintf(paste0("%.", n, "f"), x))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4())
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr     min       lq   median      uq      max neval
# f1() 288.594 294.6525 298.5165 302.5325 544.610   100
# f2() 319.022 324.4970 327.0815 331.4695 600.179   100
# f3()   9.799  12.4140  13.6315  13.9910 142.313   100
# f4()  40.198  42.6590  45.9945  46.6180 342.098   100
```

Comment: Can I prevent it form jumping to sci notation? `as.character(round(0.0001, 4))`

Comment: Perfect. It's still not clear to me why your `sub` is so much faster than `drop0trailing`; it does exactly that.

Comment: @Jeroen For me it was also a surprise to see that the `format` function is so slow.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works (if you want to have three digits **overall**):

```
as.numeric(formatC(x, flag="#", digits=3))
```

If your numbers are all between 0 and 1, then specifying  `as.numeric(formatC(x, flag="#", digits=(n+1)))` gives you the answer.